# Ruby with RSpec NoMethodError: undefined method length for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby and RSpec trying to write a unit case for string length. I have 3 rb files as follows
1. Calling file

```
require_relative 'ruby_final_operations'
require_relative 'ruby_helper'
require 'uri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'prime'
module RubyOperations
 # Public: Various commands for the user to interact with RubyCommand.
  class Command
    res = RubyOperations::Operations.new
res.letter_count(res.inputstr)
```

2nd File - Method Implementation

```
    require_relative 'ruby_helper'
require 'logger'
$FILE_LOG = RubyOperations.create_log(File.expand_path('~/RubyOperations_LOG.log'), Logger::DEBUG)
$STD_LOG = RubyOperations.create_log(nil, Logger::INFO)
module RubyOperations
class Operations

def inputstr
      RubyOperations.log('Enter the String:[Length 20]',:BOTH)
      @str = gets.chomp
      raise StandardError if @str =~ /\d/ || @str.empty? || @str.length > 20
    rescue StandardError,ArgumentError => e
      RubyOperations.log(e,:ERROR)
    end

def letter_count(str)
    result = @str.length
      RubyOperations.log("The number of letters in the string: #{result}",:BOTH)
end
```

3rd file - RSpec

```
require 'ruby_final_operations'

describe 'RubyOperations' do
  describe 'Operations' do
   subject = RubyOperations::Operations.new
describe '.letter_count' do
     context 'when operation is provided' do
      it 'returns letter count' do
        allow(subject.letter_count("hello").to receive(:result).and_return(5)
      end
    end
   end
```

The problem is that in the 2nd File he argument is 'str' but the typed string is stored is '@str'.
How can I pass the string 'hello' from the rspec file to test this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues:

**Calling a instance_method with an argument that is not used**

```
def letter_count #get rid of argument, the argument does nothing, 
                 #basically it looks you added the argument, 
                 # just, so you can call the other method there.
```

**Make your main simple, with a clear sequence**

```
res.inputstr
res.letter_count
```

**But about your actual question, in your test you change the wrong thing the wrong method**

```
allow(subject.letter_count("hello").to receive(:result).and_return(5)
# letter count should do the log entry, not return five, at least that what your method say
```

So you probably want to set the @str before you test the letter_count method.

```
 subject.instance_variable_set("hello")
 # then test for what you expect the method to return
 expect(subject.letter_count).to eq(5)
 # this specific test will fail, because you are doing a log entry, and not return the length on letter_count.
```

Comment: Thanks, was able to fix :)